# Ruby on Rails: Code Rot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, frameworks

Long story short, I start up my system, and when I tell Rubymine to run development I get this.

```
/home/barnabus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /home/barnabus/Projects/Ruby/houston/script/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development
/home/barnabus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:9:in `<module:MimeResponds>': /home/barnabus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
from /home/barnabus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:6:in `<module:ActionController>'
from /home/barnabus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/barnabus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:196:in `<class:Base>'
from /home/barnabus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:171:in `<module:ActionController>'
from /home/barnabus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/barnabus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/cancan-1.6.10/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb:394:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/barnabus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/barnabus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /home/barnabus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /home/barnabus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/barnabus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/cancan-1.6.10/lib/cancan.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/barnabus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /home/barnabus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /home/barnabus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /home/barnabus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
from /home/barnabus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /home/barnabus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/barnabus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
from /home/barnabus/Projects/Ruby/houston/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/barnabus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
from /home/barnabus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/barnabus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /home/barnabus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/barnabus/Projects/Ruby/houston/script/rails:6:in `require'
from /home/barnabus/Projects/Ruby/houston/script/rails:6:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have never seen this error, and I don't really know where and how to proceed as so much of this is happening in framework code.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was to see that it is a gem that is acting up.  So I went and uninstalled the gem by running this.

```
bundle exec gem uninstall actionpack
```

It complained about dependencies.

```
You have requested to uninstall the gem:
actionpack-3.2.8
actionmailer-3.2.8 depends on [actionpack (= 3.2.8)]
railties-3.2.8 depends on [actionpack (= 3.2.8)]
rails-3.2.8 depends on [actionpack (= 3.2.8)]
rspec-rails-2.12.2 depends on [actionpack (>= 3.0)]
simple_form-2.0.4 depends on [actionpack (~> 3.0)]
If you remove this gems, one or more dependencies will not be met.
Continue with Uninstall? [Yn]  Y
```

But that doesn't matter because we are going to reinstall it.

```
Successfully uninstalled actionpack-3.2.8
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `delete' for #<Bundler::SpecSet:0x00000002c53b20>
```

After that was done I had to reinstall it and to do that I just ran

```
bundle install
```

And I was back on track.

Comment: "Thug life"? How about adding something useful and informative?

Comment: @meagar sigh, it's been changed.